# Accessing JSON Elements W/ Python

Tags: python, json, multidimensional-array, element

I want to access the individual data for 'vin', 'make', 'year', etc and export to a csv. I have tried accessing it by

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=15)

response_json = response.json()
#print(response_json)

for item in response_json['data']['hits']['hits']:
    
      active_year = item['year']
      active_make = item['make']
      active_model = item['model']
      active_trim = item['trim']
      active_vin = item['vin']
      active_mileage = item['mileage']
      active_basePrice = item['price']
                    
    
      print(str(active_year) + " " + active_vin + " " + active_make)
```

I get a KeyError: 'year'

This is part of the JSON tree I am working with

```
`{
    "data": {
        "took": 31,
        "timed_out": false,
        "hits": {
            "total": 15786,
            "hits": [
                {
                    "_source": {
                        "vin": "JTHBW1GG0H2142332",
                        "stockNumber": "",
                        "bodyType": "Sedan",
                        "interiorPhotoUrl": "https://cdn.spincar.com/swipetospin-viewers/vroomadesaatlanta/jthbw1gg0h2142332/20201203212657.Z81AZWJL/closeups/cu-10.jpg",
                        "diesel": 0,
                        "leadFlagPhotoUrl": "https://cdn.spincar.com/swipetospin-viewers/vroomadesaatlanta/jthbw1gg0h2142332/20201203212657.Z81AZWJL/closeups/cu-0.jpg",
                        "listingPrice": 26980,
                        "color": "Black",
                        "year": 2017,`
```

I am just a bit confused on the syntax as I have access data from a 2D array in this same manner.

Comment: You're forgetting that all that data is within the `'_source'` key of the top dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skipped the '_source' section of json. This should fix it.

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=15)

response_json = response.json()
#print(response_json)

for item in response_json['data']['hits']['hits']:
      source = item['_source'] # THIS WAS MISSING
    
      active_year = source['year']
      active_make = source['make']
      active_model = source['model']
      active_trim = source['trim']
      active_vin = source['vin']
      active_mileage = source['mileage']
      active_basePrice = source['price']
                    
    
      print(str(active_year) + " " + active_vin + " " + active_make)
```